# Beginner level ruby on rails prepwork for bootcamp, which solution is correct?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Given this problem, which answer would you use? (the first is the boot camp’s method and the second is mine) When testing the boot camp’s method it never returns the desired answer but when testing mine it works. I feel like as a beginner there is no way the boot camp is wrong so I’m wondering if there is something I am missing. Thanks for the help! Sorry the question is formatted weird. I am VERY new. (This is for Jumpstart for App Academy so basically pre-boot camp boot camp)

**Write a method that returns an array of the digits of a non-negative integer in descending order and as strings, e.g**:

```
descending_digits(4291) #=> ["9", "4", "2", "1"]

def descending_digits(int)

**# your code goes here**

end
```

**#method 1**

```
int.to_s.split("").sort.reverse
```

**#method 2**

```
int.sort.reverse.join(" ").split
```

Comment: #method 2 cannot work since you can't call sort on a `int` or `string` data type

Comment: I suppose you misunderstood the question. You're supposed to supply an integer (4291) and get an array of string.

Comment: Yes. You are right. I was starting with an array rather than integer. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
method 1 is correct here is explanation

a = 4291 # a is variable number 4291
=> 4291
irb(main):005:0> a.to_s  # convert a to string
=> "4291"
irb(main):006:0> a.to_s.split("") # split each character
=> ["4", "2", "9", "1"]
irb(main):007:0> a.to_s.split("").sort # sort it, default is ascending
=> ["1", "2", "4", "9"]
irb(main):008:0> a.to_s.split("").sort.reverse # reverse it to descending
=> ["9", "4", "2", "1"]

method 2

a = 4291
a.sort # will return an error
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The way you laid out the solution really helped me understand the logic.

Answer (score 0):

Your method (#method 2) is incorrect since `sort` is an array method and not a `string` or `int` method.

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-sort

Comment: Thank you! You are right. I was starting with an array instead of an integer.

Comment: No problem happy to help